# Сокращения слов

Tags: сокращения

Кто-нибудь знает, как правильно сокращать телефон и факс? Какие сокращения являются правильными?

тел./факс? т./ф.? т/ф?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

тел./факс - [словарь сокращений](http://www.sokr.ru/%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB.%20%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81).

Comment: А т/ф с точками или без неправомерно? Главное, что интересует - нужны ли точки?

Comment: В словаре только один вариант. Но если вы хотите сократить т./ф., то только с точками (согласно правилу сокращения слов: ставится точка как знак сокращения, когда слово с отсеченной конечной частью при чтении вслух произносится в полной, а не сокращенной форме. Напр.: г. — при чтении произносят год, а не гэ (Мильчин А.Э.)